# Error React createElement type is invalid expected a string for built-in components or a class function for composite components but got object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to change my client side rendered react app to be rendered on server side. I am using React with TypeScript. Here is the error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
/.../node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6984
    throw fatalError;
```

Here is my package.json dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/register": "^7.18.9",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.186",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.5",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.1",
    "ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "prettier": "2.7.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
  }
```

And here is my rendered.js class where the error seems to be triggered:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'

// import our main App component
import App from '../../src/App';

const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

export default (req, res, next) => {

    // point to the html file created by CRA's build tool
    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'build', 'index.html');

    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, htmlData) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('err', err);
            return res.status(404).end()
        }

        // render the app as a string
        const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />);

        // inject the rendered app into our html and send it
        return res.send(
            htmlData.replace(
                '<div id="root"></div>',
                `<div id="root">${html}</div>`
            )
        );
    });
}
```

And here is my index.tsx file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./styles/index.css";
import {App} from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import * as _ from 'lodash'


// const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
//   document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement
// );
// root.hydrate(
//     <BrowserRouter>
//       <App />
//     </BrowserRouter>
// );

ReactDOM.hydrate(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I've tried changing the imports of App.tsx although it didn't work for me.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the line in your rendered.js file

from

```
import App from '../../src/App';
```

to

```
import { default as App } from '../../src/App';
```

I think that's because you use babel register or other transformer, transform default export into { default: [function App] }, so that the React.createElement function place the object but not the Component function into type field